# AVPictureInPictureController doesn't automatically start picture-in-picture when backgrounding the app

Tags: ios, avkit, ios14

When creating a custom video player using the `AVPlayer` + `AVPlayerLayer` + `AVPictureInPictureController` for a iPhone running iOS 14 (beta 7) the video does not automatically enter picture-in-picture-mode when the app enters the background after `player.start()` is called from a UIButton action.

The issue does not reproduce using the `AVPlayerViewController` which seems to indicate a problem with the `AVPictureInPictureController` on iOS 14 in general, but I was wondering if anyone else had run into this problem and know of any workarounds. I've also filed this problem with Apple under `rdar://8620271`

Sample code.

```swift
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import AVKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    private let player = AVPlayer(url: URL(string: "https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4")!)
    private var pictureInPictureController: AVPictureInPictureController!
    private var playerView: PlayerView!
    private var playButton: UIButton!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        playerView = PlayerView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 44, width: view.bounds.width, height: 200))
        playerView.backgroundColor = .black
        playerView.playerLayer.player = player
        view.addSubview(playerView)

        playButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: view.bounds.midX - 50, y: playerView.frame.maxY + 20, width: 100, height: 22))
        playButton.setTitleColor(.blue, for: .normal)
        playButton.setTitle("Play", for: .normal)
        playButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(play), for: .touchUpInside)
        view.addSubview(playButton)

        pictureInPictureController = AVPictureInPictureController(playerLayer: playerView.playerLayer)

        do {
            let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
            try audioSession.setCategory(.playback)
            try audioSession.setMode(.moviePlayback)
            try audioSession.setActive(true)
        } catch let e {
            print(e.localizedDescription)
        }
    }

    @objc func play() {
        player.play()
    }
}

class PlayerView: UIView {
    override class var layerClass: AnyClass {
        return AVPlayerLayer.self
    }

    var playerLayer: AVPlayerLayer! {
        return layer as? AVPlayerLayer
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The root cause of the problem ended up being twofold:

1. `AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)` must be called **before** the `AVPictureInPictureController` is initialised.
2. The frame size for the `AVPlayerLayer` must have a aspect ratio no greater than 16/9 (filed as a separate bug, `rdar://8689203`)
3. For iPads, the video must be the same width as the device (in any given orientation). No separate rdar, as Apple have acknowledged the other bug already.

(The 2nd issues is not present in the example above)

Apple have acknowledged these bugs, and reported back to me that they have been / will be fixed (a rare case of a radar actually resulting in a reply!)

Comment: Any tips on how to check the frame size for the avplayerlayer? Still doesn't work.

Comment: That’s very interesting insights. I already noticed that I need to set `playerController.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill` in order for it to work (my video is a portrait iPhone screen recording, so I assume it’s related to the aspect ratio bug).

Answer (score 12):

Starting iOS 14.2, Apple has exposed an api to start PIP when app goes into background:

```
if #available(iOS 14.2, *) {
   pictureInPictureController.canStartPictureInPictureAutomaticallyFromInline = true
}
```

Additionally, it is worth noting that Apple has forbidden to start picture-in-picture without user manually tapping the button. It will result in app rejection.
Best bet is to use Apple's API mentioned above to avoid rejection.

Comment: DAMN!!! Thanks a lot! I have been trying to find out how to get this working correctly all week!!

Comment: This solved an issue for me.

Also, I have to clarify that using `canStartPictureInPictureAutomaticallyFromInline` should not result in your app rejection since you do not actually start picture-in-picture without the user manually tapping the button as Apple requires — the iPadOS does, while the user can disable this behavior in system settings. 

You are actually expected to use this property, since Apple presented it in the [What's new in AVKit][1] video at WWDC 21 session.

  [1]: https://developer.apple.com/wwdc21/1029

Comment: Very helpful. We suffered this issue for a long time and this answer saved us!