# PiP works on iPhone but not iPad

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avplayer, picture-in-picture

In iOS 14, when I set up an `AVPlayerViewController`, and set the player's delegate, if I press the home button on an iPhone, the delegate function `playerViewControllerDidStartPictureInPicture` gets called and I can see the PiP on the phone's home screen. However, in the same app, if I press the home button on an iPad, that delegate method does not get called, and PiP doesn't start.

Is there anything I could possibly be missing? Is there a way to programmatically activate PiP? The goal is to show PiP on iPad when the user presses the home button.

This is what the code looks like:

```
                let videoURL = URL(string: url)!
                let player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL)
                playerView = AVPlayerViewController()
                guard let playerView = playerView else { return }

                playerView.player = player
                playerView.delegate = self
                playerView.allowsPictureInPicturePlayback = true
```

Comment: I fixed this by adding `playerView.canStartPictureInPictureAutomaticallyFromInline = true`

Comment: Thank you, it saved my day too. I think Apply should clarify this point. Otherwise, we can consider this as a kind of unintentional behavior of iOS on iPhones.

Comment: There was originally some bugs as well, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63739978/avpictureinpicturecontroller-doesnt-automatically-start-picture-in-picture-when/